# React Native API Authentication: No username/password?

Tags: authentication, react-native, jwt, api-design

Apologies for the general nature of this question. Hoping this doesn't get shot down as "too broad", but oh well, here goes:

I'm writing a React Native app that is purely informational (medical information), with a Rails API for the back-end.

The first main question I have is whether its necessary (or a good idea) to use authentication at all. We don't want the user to have to enter any information to use it (username, password, etc). They should just be able to download the app and jump right in to use it and read the information it provides.

However, I'm thinking that I would at least want the API to only respond to someone hitting it from within the React Native app (or not? Is it considered a normal practice to have an API completely exposed in the case of an app like this which is purely information and doesn't have users, like a website?)

Second - at some point we may want to be able to store some simple preferences for that user (I.E., are they a patient or a doctor, so we can tailor the materials based on that / send them to a different home screen when the open the app). Wondering what strategy someone might use to store simple preferences if the user doesn't ever create an account?

Answer (score 1):

> I would at least want the API to only respond to someone hitting it
>   from within the React Native app.

This probably can't be done, as in a mobile app everyone has access to your client secret and can try to reverse engineer your code.
You could make it more difficult by sending a dynamically generated token to your API on the request, for example, a hash based on a time frame, and check if the hash was sent the correct way. Then, you'd have to obfuscate the code in order to make it difficult for someone to reverse engineer it.

> Second - at some point we may want to be able to store some simple
>   preferences for that user (I.E., are they a patient or a doctor, so we
>   can tailor the materials based on that / send them to a different home
>   screen when the open the app). Wondering what strategy someone might
>   use to store simple preferences if the user doesn't ever create an
>   account?

If you use a Parse Server instance as your backend, you could benefit from the anonymous user functionality. As you're using a Rails API, you could generate a uuid for each installation of the app and save the preferences on your database based on that uuid. If you don't need those preferences stored on your backend, just store any information you need on the device through any abstraction of AsyncStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not need authentication when it comes down to it - there are no users.

I could verify that the data is coming from my app based on a user agent or a hard coded password. SSL should help keep those secret.

But yeah, there would be nothing preventing someone from disassembling the app and getting that information. Great idea by @felipe-martim about generating a dynamic token.

I really just want to prevent basic abuse, and I could deal with that if it ever happened, or protect myself with something like Rack-attack.

And storing user preferences locally should work just fine for local preferences.

Bottom line is that I'll deal with this if I ever need to / the client budget allows for it!